# How do I get the updated document back after I call document.save() function in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, jwt

I'm trying to create a settings page where the user can update their credentials (Username and such)
The length of the username is 5 < length < 30. Therefore, if the user enters a username that doesn't follow these rules the inbuilt validation kicks in and prevents the user from saving these credentials. Following this, I also update their JWT Token so that the changes get reflected in the dashboard.

server code (node.js)

```
/* ................ 
code to update other fields
...............*/

if (newUsername && newUsername !== user.username) {
     user.username = newUsername;
     messages.push({
          message: 'Username updated successfuly',
          error: false,
     });
}

await user.save({ j: true }, (err) => {
     if (err) {
     messages.push({ message: err.message, error: true });
     }
     res.clearCookie(accessTokenName);
     createJWTCookie(user, res);
     res.render('settings', { messages });
});
```

However, this doesn't work like I want it to. The inbuilt validation does kick in and prevents saving of invalid fields but the token still gets updated with wrong info. I believe this is because the (user) argument of `createJWTCookie` still has information from before the `user.save()` method was run.

Even if I `console.log(user)` after the `user.save()` method has been run it contains the invalid input from the user. But if I logout and login again (This creates a new JWT Cookie with the user from the database), the token that is generated only has valid fields. This means that only valid fields were updated while the other changes were discarded.

How do I get the updated user document after `user.save()` has been run so I can create a valid JWT cookie without the user having to logout and login again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling user.save() doesn't make any changes to your user object, it just updates the document on your database. If the inbuilt validation kicks in due to an invalid username, it will prevent the save() from happening (which is good to have as a fail-safe), but won't affect the actual user object in your code.

To solve this, you would need to write in your own validation when updating the user object. This should work:

```
if (newUsername && newUsername !== user.username && newUsername.length > 5 && newUserName.length < 30) {
 user.username = newUsername;
 messages.push({
      message: 'Username updated successfuly',
      error: false,
 });
```

}

Comment: I see, is their anyway to automate this? For example, suppose your model is extremely complex and every field has certain restrictions to go with it. How would you deal with something like that then?

Comment: I think it would still be best to write your own validation for each case. If you're adamant on using the inbuilt validation of mongoose to do it for you, I guess you could technically do another query to get the user document after the save(), since that wouldn't have changed if the save() failed.

Comment: Thanks for all your help :) Much appreciated!